# jquery ajax post returns me 'false' before timeout happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery returns me 'false' before timeout happens. I have to call the API which takes much time to get result. So I changed timeout to 5 minutes. When the API takes short time(about under 1 minute), it works. But if the server API takes long time(around 2 to 3 minutes), page doesn't show me anything. Moreover, timeout error trigger doesn't works at all. It silently doesn't show me anything. After debugging the code, I've found that ajax just return 'false'(value is false) after 2 to 3 minutes which is under timeout limit.

This is not server problem. I've checked server log. Other client(I've used chrome plugin [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)) return correct value on this API, even if the API takes 2 to 3 minutes.

I can't grab clue why this things happens. I thought there exists timeout limit on browser. But
'postman' is also just webpage which is running under chrome. Are there any hidden setting besides 'timeout' attribute at jQuery ajax? I can't find that kinds of things til now. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Below is the code i used.

```
$(function() {
    $('#layerBtn').click(function(){
        $("#contents_body").html("");
        $.ajax({
            data: '',
            url: '/some/where',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout : 300000,
            success: function(result){
                $("#contents_body").append(beautify(result));
            },
            error : function(x,t,m){
                if(t==="timeout"){
                    alert("got timeout."+t)
                } else{
                    alert(t)
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you test the server on `POST` or only `GET`? Might there be some cache in the way?

Comment: @JNF it's post request only. This is only one api that takes long time.

Comment: Did you validate the structure of the result?

Comment: @JNF This api is supposed to return json. The api returns well. at least, in the postman. postman automatically detecting file format, and it looks they have no problem with formatting return result(json).

Comment: Did you assert that the JSON is valid?

Comment: @JNF Actually, i can't get any value besides weird 'false' from jquery ajax when it takes long time. I can just see the values by using the postman when it takes long. returnning JSON is valid format. I just checked it with other json formatter and it returns me that it is valid. (i got values from server log and postman)